# SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems() and Sharepoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointframework

Does SharePoint framework have its own way of getting selected items from a list or do we still need to use SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()?

If latter, how do I make it available in a Typescript/spfx solution?

Answer (score 0):

CSOM SharePoint has nothing to do with third-party frameworks, it works great on its own, see a large number of examples and [articles](https://mickdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/08/ribbons-customization-in-sharepoint.html) on the Internet.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
```

Answer (score -1):

it is bit different. To learn about [Create Dropdown in Ract](https://www.codementor.io/chrisharrington/create-a-dropdown-using-react-js--font-awesome-and-less-css-du1087rsx).

We have to set state in react. On selected Item change it will call the methods which will set the ItemCountry in the class.

Add this to your Render Method.

```
<select value={this.state.ItemCountry} className={styles.myinput} onChange=
{this.onChangeSelect.bind(this)}>{options}
                        </select>
```

Add this to your constructor

```
this.state = {           
        ItemCountry: "Select Country",          
    };
```

Add this method in your class.

```
public onChangeSelect(event: any): void {
    this.setState({ ItemCountry: event.target.value });
}
```